# Fundamental Question on randomized Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, computation-theory, probability-theory, correctness

> Problem set:
>   You are given a randomized algorithm called ALG that takes as input an undi-rected graph G and outputs in linear time, a number k with the following property: With probability at least 1/n, the number k is the size of a minimum cut of G. Someone now has the idea to increase the probability of getting the size of a minimumcut by running ALG n times (which results in an O(n^2) algorithm).  Is this a reasonable approach and what is the main difference of the above algorithm to the Karger's algorithm?

P("ALG gets minCut") = 1/n

P("ALG gets minCut if repeated n times") = 1 - (1 - 1/n)^n <  1 - 1/e

So we improve Probability from linear to constant but we reduce the running time from linear to quadratic.

> Given: Karger runs in O(n^2 log n) and gets minimum cut with probability at least 1/log n

so to get the same Probability of succeed we can just do log (n) repeats on Kargers so that  1- (1- 1/log n)^log(n)  = 1 - e^(-1) as for the ALG algorithm.

n x ALG: Runtime = O(n^2),  Probability of succeed 1 - e^(-1)

log(n) x Karger: Runtime = O(log n n^2 log n ),  Probability of succeed 1 - e^(-1)

If there where such an ALG Argorithm it would be NOT better then Kargers one.

---

Is this analyses correct? Is there something more I need to mention?